# How to extract type arguments and type parameters from a type aliases references other type aliases?

Tags: typescript, tsc, typescript-compiler-api

How would one use the TypeScript compiler API 4.2+ (or ts-morph 10+) to extract from the following:

```
export type A = Record<string,number>
```

1. The fact that exported type alias A
2. is a reference to `Record`
3. and passes it `string` & `number`
4. and that `Record` is also a type alias
5. with two type parameters,
6. getting each one's names/constraints/defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the behaviour change in TS 4.2, the best thing I can figure out so far is to traverse the AST and inspect the type node of the type alias. There might be a better way though...

In ts-morph:

```
const aTypeAlias = sourceFile.getTypeAliasOrThrow("A");
const typeNode = aTypeAlias.getTypeNodeOrThrow();

if (Node.isTypeReferenceNode(typeNode)) {
  // or do typeNode.getType().getTargetType()
  const targetType = typeNode.getTypeName().getType();
  console.log(targetType.getText()); // Record<K, T>

  for (const typeArg of typeNode.getTypeArguments()) {
    console.log(typeArg.getText()); // string both times
  }
}
```

With the compiler API:

```
const typeAliasDecl = sourceFile.statements[0] as ts.TypeAliasDeclaration;
const typeRef = typeAliasDecl.type as ts.TypeReferenceNode;

console.log(checker.typeToString(checker.getTypeAtLocation(typeRef.typeName))); // Record<K, T>

for (const typeArg of typeRef.typeArguments ?? []) {
  console.log(checker.typeToString(checker.getTypeAtLocation(typeArg))); // string
}
```

Comment: Thanks David! It seems so odd to have to go between the AST and the type checker to get a clear picture of this info. The basis for this complexity I guess is how internally TS erases information about type aliases.

Comment: @JasonKuhrt you may want to open an issue on the TypeScript repo asking if there's a way to access that type.

Comment: In the latest version typeArg.getText() gives me "K" and "T" as type arguments. any idea how to get "string"s again?